# $f \in C([0, 1]$ and $|f| \in AC([0, 1])$ imply $f \in AC([0, 1])$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function. $|f|$ is absolutely continuous on $[0, 1]$. Prove that $f \in AC([0, 1])$.

Any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Are we given that $f$ is real-valued? This is clearly nonsense for complex-valued functions; it would imply that any continuous $f$ with $|f|=1$ was AC.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich $f$ is real-valued. Made changes to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Suppose $x<y$. If $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have the same sign (or one of them is $0$) then $$|f(x)-f(y)|=\big|\,|f(x)|-|f(y)|\,\big|.$$ If $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have different signs then there exists $z\in(x,y)$ with $f(z)=0$, and now $$|f(x)-f(y)|=\big|\,|f(x)|-|f(z)|\,\big|+\big|\,|f(z)|-|f(y)|\,\big|$$(and $y-x=(y-z)+(z-x)$).

**Hmm:** That makes the result pretty clear, at least to me. When I think about writing the actual proof it seems like at least the notation might be cleaner if we observed this:

> > If $x<y$ there exists $z\in[x,y]$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|=\big|\,|f(x)|-|f(z)|\,\big|+\big|\,|f(z)|-|f(y)|\,\big|$.

(In the first case above let $x=z$.)

Comment: I suggest changing $z\in(x,y)$ to $z\in[x,y]$. This covers the case of $f(x)=0$ or $f(y)=0$. Alternatively, “if $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have the same sign” could be “if $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ have the same sign _or_ one of them is zero.”